# Vue3 does not re-render parent component if the state changed on SSR

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, pinia

In SSR mode, Vue3 does not re-render the parent component if the child component changes its state.

Live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yhw2db?file=src%2FApp.vue,index.html,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue&terminal=dev)

Let's say we have the `App.vue` component as follows:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import useStore from './store';
const store = useStore();
</script>

<template>
  Test in parent component: {{ store.test }}
  <HelloWorld msg="Vite + Vue" />
</template>
```

And the `HelloWorld.vue` component that will change the `store.test` on the `onServerPrefetch` hook

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onServerPrefetch } from 'vue';

defineProps<{ msg: string }>();
import useStore from '../store';
const store = useStore();
onServerPrefetch(() => {
  store.test = true;
});
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  Test inside child component: {{ store.test }}
</template>
```

The **expected output** when we serve the app from the server is as follows:

```
Test in parent component: true
Test inside child component: true
```

But the **actual output** is as follows:

```
Test in parent component: false
Test inside child component: true
```

I understand that there is no reactivity on SSR so the parent component can not re-render if its state is changed by children. But it is weird. On an app that strongly depends on central state management, this case will happen very frequently.

So is there any workaround or idea to get rid of that behavior?

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: SSR renders its static output just once. Everything else happens inside the browser, after the hydration is completed. SSR is intended to improve your SEO - not to run your application on the server instead of the browser. SSR simply gives some HTML/CSS that the browser can immediately show on screen or a crawler can ingest. All dynamics will still happen only inside the browser - not on the server.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for your comment. I understand that SSR serves static output just once. But there are so many use cases that we need to update the output based on dynamic data. SEO is one of them. So I'm just looking for a workaround. If there is none, I have to change the flow of code.

Comment: IF your data changes - you will have to rebuild the SSR bundle. This is usually handled by a webhook in your CI/CD. Once these static HTML/CSS/JavaScript files are emitted - there is nobody on the server to execute this JavaScript code to dynamically fetch data and generate new HTML at the moment of receiving the HTTP GET request from the Google crawler. The whole idea of SSR is that it is static - and only changes/rebuilds when its dependencies (e.g. data source) change.

Comment: Actually, it does not relate to CI/CD. I think you are confused between SSR and SSG, aren't you? In SSR, the HTML is generated on the fly for each request, by a node server. SSR can actually serve dynamic data. But yeah, it does not reactive. The parent component is rendered first then its children, I guess. I can't accept that behavior at first but seem like I have no choice

Comment: Hmm, you might be right - I confused a bit SSR and SSG. According to Vue [manual](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#reactivity-on-the-server) the reactivity is disabled and only 2 lifecycle hooks are supported.